# Read product name with ipmiutil raw command

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I would like to read Product name with IPMI raw command. I could use "fru" like this:

```
c:\Testing\ipmiutil>ipmiutil.exe fru -b -N <address> -U root -P root
ipmiutil ver 3.01
ifru: version 3.01
Connecting to node  <address>
-- BMC version 1.48, IPMI version 2.0

.... some data

[Baseboard,20,00] Product Name        : <Product Name>

.... some data
```

However, in my case this command takes like minute to issue, so it's far too long. I figured I would read it directly with Raw command. However, I don't understand how should I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no simple raw command that will work for getting the product name.  Multiple requests are typically made to build up the block of data containing the FRU product information.  Then the block of data must be parsed properly to extract the product name and fields are variable length.  As an example, here's the block of product info for an Intel motherboard I have using FreeIPMI's ipmi-fru --debug.

```
=====================================================
Product Info Area 
=====================================================
[  HEX DUMP ..... ] = HEX[104B]
[ 01h 0Dh 00h C4h 63h 72h 61h 79h ]
[ CDh 63h 72h 61h 79h 2Dh 32h 36h ]
[ 32h 38h 2Dh 6Ch 73h 6Dh CAh 2Eh ]
[ 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh ]
[ 2Eh C9h 30h 30h 30h 2Dh 30h 31h ]
[ 37h 32h 39h C9h 61h 70h 31h 32h ]
[ 31h 31h 35h 37h 35h D4h 2Eh 2Eh ]
[ 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh ]
[ 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh 2Eh ]
[ 2Eh 2Eh C0h C1h 00h 00h 00h 00h ]
[ 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h ]
[ 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h ]
[ 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 7Fh ]
```

The product name here begins on the second line with "63h 72h 61h 79h" ("cray").

Answer (score 0):

Use "dmidecode" utility for windows.